# Add symbol between characters of MAC Addresses

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a list of MAC Addresses and I need to add a ":" every 2 characters.

I mean, if I have this:

```
23396 - FFFF00400001 - Lantastic
23397 - FFFF01E00004 - Lantastic
23379 - 0C000C0000 - ISL-Frame
23054 - F8D756 - Simm Tronic Limited
23055 - F8D7BF - REV Ritter GmbH
```

I need to parse to have this:

```
23396 - FF:FF:00:40:00:01 - Lantastic
23397 - FF:FF:01:E0:00:04 - Lantastic
23379 - 0C:00:0C:00:00 - ISL-Frame
23054 - F8:D7:56 - Simm Tronic Limited
23055 - F8:D7:BF - REV Ritter GmbH
```

It is possible? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) with its substitution command:

```
perl -lane '$F[2] =~ s/(..)(?!$)/$1:/g; print qq|@F|' infile
```

It yields:

```
23396 - FF:FF:00:40:00:01 - Lantastic
23397 - FF:FF:01:E0:00:04 - Lantastic
23379 - 0C:00:0C:00:00 - ISL-Frame
23054 - F8:D7:56 - Simm Tronic Limited
23055 - F8:D7:BF - REV Ritter GmbH
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/../,":&",$3);sub(/:/,"")}1' file
23396 - FF:FF:00:40:00:01 - Lantastic
23397 - FF:FF:01:E0:00:04 - Lantastic
23379 - 0C:00:0C:00:00 - ISL-Frame
23054 - F8:D7:56 - Simm Tronic Limited
23055 - F8:D7:BF - REV Ritter GmbH
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly short, but works:

```
awk '{n=split($3,a,"");s="";for (i=1;i<=n-2;i+=2) s=s sprintf("%s%s:",a[i],a[i+1]);s=s a[n-1]a[n];$3=s}1' file
23396 - FF:FF:00:40:00:01 - Lantastic
23397 - FF:FF:01:E0:00:04 - Lantastic
23379 - 0C:00:0C:00:00 - ISL-Frame
23054 - F8:D7:56 - Simm Tronic Limited
23055 - F8:D7:BF - REV Ritter GmbH
```